# SQL Server - Display two different dates on two different lines

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm currently struggling to get my query to display two dates on two lines. i.e. I have two lines, with two columns for two dates. I need one line to have null then date, the second line to have date then null. Example shown in image below - only one of these dates needs to show up per line.

[Two lines two dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkN0c.jpg)

Google has not been my friend thus far because it's a rather obscure thing to try and describe to the search engine. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Full query is below:

```
    WITH CTE AS
 (
 SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY person_code ORDER BY unit_instance_code) AS rn
 FROM learner_aims
 )

SELECT DISTINCT p.person_code [ID],
p.forename [Forename],
        p.surname [Surname],
        uio.long_description [CourseDesc],
    CASE rn
    WHEN 1 THEN NULL
    WHEN 2 THEN CONVERT(DATE, sub.[GIL Start Date], 103) 
    END AS [GIL Start Date],
    CASE rn
    WHEN 1 THEN CONVERT(DATE, sub.[Non-GIL Start Date], 103)
    WHEN 2 THEN NULL
    END AS [Non-GIL Start Date]
--    CONVERT(DATE, sub.[GIL Start Date], 103) [GIL Start Date],
--    CONVERT(DATE, sub.[Non-GIL Start Date], 103) [Non-GIL Start Date]
FROM people p
INNER JOIN learner_aims la ON p.person_code = la.person_code
INNER JOIN unit_instance_occurrences uio ON uio.uio_id = la.uio_id
INNER JOIN cte ON cte.person_code = p.person_code
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT p.person_code [ID],
    p.forename [Forename],
    p.surname [Surname],
  MIN(fy22.earlieststartdate) [GIL Start Date],
  MIN(fy22sub.earlieststartdate) [Non-GIL Start Date]
FROM people p
INNER JOIN learner_aims la ON p.person_code = la.person_code
INNER JOIN unit_instance_occurrences uio ON uio.uio_id = la.uio_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT p.person_code [ID],
        p.forename [Forename],
        p.surname [Surname],
        uio.course_occurrence_code [CourseCode],
        uio.long_description [CourseDesc],
        uio.owning_organisation [OwningOrg],
        uio.offering_organisation [OfferingOrg],
        la.uio_id [uio_id],
        MIN(CONVERT(DATE, la.start_date, 103)) [EarliestStartDate]
    FROM people p
    INNER JOIN learner_aims la ON p.person_code = la.person_code
    INNER JOIN unit_instance_occurrences uio ON uio.uio_id = la.uio_id
    WHERE la.ilr = 'Y'
        AND la.funding_year = '22'
        AND (
            uio.course_occurrence_code LIKE 'GIL%'
            OR uio.course_occurrence_code LIKE 'SEED%'
            )
    GROUP BY p.person_code,
        p.forename,
        p.surname,
        uio.course_occurrence_code,
        uio.long_description,
        uio.owning_organisation,
        uio.offering_organisation,
        la.uio_id
    ) [FY22] ON fy22.id = la.person_code
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT p.person_code [ID],
        p.forename [Forename],
        p.surname [Surname],
        uio.course_occurrence_code [CourseCode],
        uio.long_description [CourseDesc],
        uio.owning_organisation [OwningOrg],
        uio.offering_organisation [OfferingOrg],
        la.uio_id [uio_id],
        MIN(CONVERT(DATE, la.start_date, 103)) [EarliestStartDate]
    FROM people p
    INNER JOIN learner_aims la ON p.person_code = la.person_code
    INNER JOIN unit_instance_occurrences uio ON uio.uio_id = la.uio_id
    WHERE la.ilr = 'Y'
        AND la.funding_year = '22'
        AND uio.course_occurrence_code NOT LIKE 'GIL%'
        AND uio.course_occurrence_code NOT LIKE 'SEED%'
        AND la.person_code IN (
            SELECT la.person_code [ID]
            FROM people p
            INNER JOIN learner_aims la ON p.person_code = la.person_code
            INNER JOIN unit_instance_occurrences uio ON uio.uio_id = la.uio_id
            WHERE la.ilr = 'Y'
                AND la.funding_year = '22'
                AND (
                    uio.course_occurrence_code LIKE 'GIL%'
                    OR uio.course_occurrence_code LIKE 'SEED%'
                    )
            )
    GROUP BY p.person_code,
        p.forename,
        p.surname,
        uio.course_occurrence_code,
        uio.long_description,
        uio.owning_organisation,
        uio.offering_organisation,
        la.uio_id
    ) [FY22SUB] ON fy22sub.id = la.person_code
WHERE la.funding_year = '22' AND la.ilr = 'Y'
GROUP BY p.person_code,
        p.forename,
        p.surname
HAVING MIN(CONVERT(DATE, fy22sub.earlieststartdate, 103)) > MIN(CONVERT(DATE, fy22.earlieststartdate, 103))
) sub ON sub.id = la.person_code
WHERE la.funding_year = '22' AND la.ilr = 'Y'
ORDER BY 3, 2
```

Comment: Your sample input data and expected output?

Comment: which version of sql-sever

Comment: The expected output would be the same as the image provided, just with the top line being null date then the date, the second line having date then null date.
Sample data would essentially be a table with A, B and C as the name, two ID's against each name and two different dates against the ID's. I only want to display the date that corresponds to the ID and have the other date column blank as there should only be one date against the ID for that line.

The SQL Server is latest version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not clear what  determines if the row is first or second, I did it in base of the text in the second column as it's the only thing that changes.

So the idea here is to enumerate the rows (order by 2) and then to show the date as you want:

```
 declare @t table (id int, CourseDesc varchar(100), [GIL Start Date] date, [Non-GIL Start Date] date);
 insert into @t values(21571, 'text1', '20151116', '20160222'), (21571, 'text2', '20151116', '20160222');

 with cte as
 (
 select *,
        row_number() over(partition by id order by CourseDesc)as rn
 from @t
 )

 select id, CourseDesc,
        case rn
                when 1 then null
                when 2 then [GIL Start Date]
        end as [GIL Start Date],
        case rn
                when 1 then [Non-GIL Start Date]
                when 2 then null
        end as [Non-GIL Start Date]
from cte;
```

Comment: Thanks for that - I order by name (not shown in the example) and then the CourseDesc column. There are two rows for the two different CourseDesc's, one of which has one date attached to it, and the second has another. They don't both have the same dates attached, which is why I wanted one date per row.

With your example, as you can see I pull from multiple tables and two subqueries so I can't really declare specifics into a table, nor did it seem to agree when I replicated based on current query.

Comment: I didn't understand you well but what I did is just showing how to enumerate the rows and get the result based on the row number. Of course you should not declare any table, you should use your data instead of it: or do select into #t and use #t instead of @t without declare, or just use cte defined on your result set

Comment: Yep, did try and that and it initially didn't seem to work but it looks like I've got it working now thanks!

It has triplicated it unfortunately so some tweaking will be necessary (gives me a null/null line for both CourseDescs, and two extra lines of one in one date per row when it should just be two rows of one in one date per row (if that makes sense)